# Suse Linux ulimit -v global setting

Tags: linux, configuration, suse, ulimit

Where could be ulimit -v global setting stored?

```
> me@server:/home/me : ulimit -a
core file size          (blocks, -c) 1
data seg size           (kbytes, -d) unlimited
scheduling priority             (-e) 0
file size               (blocks, -f) unlimited
pending signals                 (-i) 61817
max locked memory       (kbytes, -l) 64
max memory size         (kbytes, -m) 6736760
open files                      (-n) 1024
pipe size            (512 bytes, -p) 8
POSIX message queues     (bytes, -q) 819200
real-time priority              (-r) 0
stack size              (kbytes, -s) 8192
cpu time               (seconds, -t) unlimited
max user processes              (-u) 61817
virtual memory          (kbytes, -v) 9695920
file locks                      (-x) unlimited
```

I can increase virtual memory by `ulimit -v INTEGER`, but this command affects only my current session.

In these files I have not defined ulimit -v

```
me@server:/home/me : cat /etc/profile | grep ulimit
# ulimit package instead to set up ulimits and your PATH.
#     ulimit -Sc 0              # don't create core files
#     ulimit -Sd $(ulimit -Hd)
#     ulimit -Ss $(ulimit -Hs)
#     ulimit -Sm $(ulimit -Hm)
me@server:/home/me : cat /etc/security/limits.conf | grep ulimit
me@server:/home/me :
```

Where could be virtual memory value **9695920** defined or where is it from?

Thanks for your help.

s.

Answer (score 0):

`ulimit -v` is in `/etc/initscript` calculated from MemTotal and SwapTotal

```
me@server:/proc : cat ./meminfo
MemTotal:        7925532 kB
SwapTotal:       4194300 kB
```